# Transit Time through Incheon (ICN) Airport (South Korea)

Tags: air-travel, transit, south-korea, icn

I am looking at flights with Korean Air that transit through Incheon Airport.
IAD (Washington DC) to ICN (South Korea), ICN to SGN (Ho Chi Min).  The layover is 1 hour 40 minutes.

Is this enough time to get through the airport and get to the next flight?  Do I have to go through any security or customs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Korean Air](https://www.koreanair.com/global/en/traveling/airport-check-in/connecting-flight-info/minimum-connection-time.html#par_titledparsys) the minimum time for International to International connections at Incheon is 45 minutes. Apparently this works even at busy times and across airlines. There is Security to go past but not Customs for Transit passengers.

[image: MCT Incheon]

Rather [dated](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/korean-air-skypass/1016710-minimum-connection-time-incheon.html).

[Incheon](http://www.airport.kr/pa/en/t/2/3/1/index.jsp) current:

[image: Incheon transit]